# Query condition to HABTM association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I want to make a query joining two models, Devices and Users in a HABTM association:

```
@device = Device.left_outer_joins(:users).where(users: {id: nil || 4})
```

I am trying to get any users that are `nil` in the join table or have the id `4`. The problem is that this query is ignoring the `nil` condition and generating this:

```
SELECT `devices`.* FROM `devices` LEFT OUTER JOIN `devices_users` ON `devices_users`.`device_id` = `devices`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `devices_users`.`user_id` WHERE `devices`.`serial` = '1111-1111-10' AND `users`.`id` = 4
```

What do I do to get this condition to be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nil || 4` evaluates to `4`, so that's why the query is ignoring nil.

If you change your query just slightly, it will work. Try this:

```
@device = Device.left_outer_joins(:users).where(users: {id: [nil, 4]})
```

ActiveRecord will take the array of `[nil, 4]` and translate it to the query you're looking for. For example, the SQL of your query would be something like this:

```
SELECT `devices`.* FROM `devices` LEFT OUTER JOIN `devices_users` ON `devices_users`.`device_id` = `devices`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `devices_users`.`user_id` WHERE `devices`.`serial` = '1111-1111-10' AND `users`.`id` = 4 OR `users`.`id` IS NULL
```

Also, this is a pretty neat part of ActiveRecord. You can even give it an array with more ids like this `[nil, 4, 5]` which will give you SQL like:

```
SELECT `devices`.* FROM `devices` LEFT OUTER JOIN `devices_users` ON `devices_users`.`device_id` = `devices`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `devices_users`.`user_id` WHERE `devices`.`serial` = '1111-1111-10' AND `users`.`id` IN (4, 5) OR `users`.`id` IS NULL
```